# How to detect flash light on/off with AutoFlash mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, gpuimage

I want to set Front flash with Auto Flash, So front camera doesn't support flash light so that I have to put One view with White color so that its working as flash light, Now my question is that What if User set Flash mode auto ? How to detect that when I have to show flash view ?

Answer (score 2):

Your **UIImagePickerController** has a property called **cameraFlashMode**.

Note that if you're supporting iOS7, the **cameraFlashMode** will always give the status as Auto. To solve this, you need to keep the flash mode status as a property.

```
BOOL isFlashModeOn = self.flashmode == (UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn || UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto);
```

Comment: I am not using UIImagePickerController I have used GPUImageVideoCamera.

Comment: It might be a custom framework. Did you check if the instance of GPUImageVideoCamera has the same property I indicated above?

Comment: Did you understand my question ? I have set my camera flash mode Auto now how to show front flash view (customer view with white background) in dark and not show it in light.